# Bootstrap 3 navbar links not lining up horizontally

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Can someone tell me why my links aren't lining up horizontally? I'm using bootstrap 3. I've referenced the bootstrap website and my code appears identical to their examples. I'm not using any custom CSS other than the bootstrap library so I am unsure how to remedy, any assistance gladly appreciated!

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->

    <title>Test</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha256-7s5uDGW3AHqw6xtJmNNtr+OBRJUlgkNJEo78P4b0yRw= sha512-nNo+yCHEyn0smMxSswnf/OnX6/KwJuZTlNZBjauKhTK0c+zT+q5JOCx0UFhXQ6rJR9jg6Es8gPuD2uZcYDLqSw==" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mainnav" aria-expanded="false">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
           </button>
         </div>

         <!-- the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
         <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="mainnav">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li><a href="#">Home</li>
              <li><a href="#">About</li>
              <li><a href="#">Contact</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
       </div>
     </nav>

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha256-KXn5puMvxCw+dAYznun+drMdG1IFl3agK0p/pqT9KAo= sha512-2e8qq0ETcfWRI4HJBzQiA3UoyFk6tbNyG+qSaIBZLyW9Xf3sWZHN/lxe9fTh1U45DpPf07yj94KsUHHWe4Yk1A==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing closing anchor tags in your unordered list.

```
<li><a href="#">Home<</a>/li>
<li><a href="#">About</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
```

Nav:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
           </button>
         </div>

         <!-- the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
         <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="mainnav">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
       </div>
     </nav>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zd9cdLh1/)